# HTML - Body height not 100%

Tags: html, css

```
body {
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #f8f8f8 ;
   background-image: url('images/bottom-right.png'); /*Images*/
   background-position: right bottom; /*Positioning*/
   background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Prevent showing multiple background images*/
}
```

so i have this code that put the image in the bottom right of the body, but the problem is its not positioning in the way that i want it. It goes to the right but not in the bottom. It's only as tall as the content inside it, just like a div or anything else. Can u please help me to achieve what i want.

here is the image -> http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2iabd3p&s=8 thanks

Comment: did you reset the `margin` and `padding`?

Comment: can you just use a div with absolute positioning `bottom:0`, `right:0`?

Comment: If j08691's answer worked you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to set a height on the `html` and remove the margin on the body:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    background-image: url('http://www.placehold.it/100x100');
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html {
    height:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZR36r/)**

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting `height: 100%;` isn't going to work in all instances. While I generally dislike using CSS2 `position` too often this may help you in this situation...

```
body, html
{
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 overflow: auto;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: In what situations won't `height: 100%` work..? It has always worked for me in the past.. j08's answer seemed to work for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

To achive what you want

I recommend you using your image seperatly and positioning it absolute.
I woudnt use the body tag and use the property background-image because your only using that image for a small section.

While managing the layers using z-index: ;

Like shown below

html

```
<div class="container">

    <img src="source/2.jpeg">

</div>
```

css

```
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container{
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
    }

    img{
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

Since you want it in the background use z-index: ;
and layer it down.

so basically z-index:0; is the comman ground.

if you want it to put the image behind you can add the css property to minus values like shown below

```
 img{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -100;
    }
```

[image: Result image]